# unzip z3 solver failing

Tags: ubuntu, server, z3

I am trying to install z3 on a remote Linux server where I am not root, I have downloaded the ubuntu matching release to my home directory on the server, when I unzip it I don't get all the folders that I need.
I installed z3 on my own MacBook (using the matching version) and it worked fine so I am giving below what the unzipping should look like vs what I get.

**server**

```
unzip z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04.zip 
Archive:  z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04.zip
  inflating: z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04/LICENSE.txt  
  inflating: z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/Microsoft.Z3.dll  

 ...

  inflating: z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04/include/z3_rcf.h  
  inflating: z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04/include/z3_macros.h

user@server:~/home/src/z3$ ls
z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04  z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04.zip


user@server:~/home/src/z3$ cd z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04/
user@server:~/home/src/z3/z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04$ ls
bin  include  LICENSE.txt
```

macbook version:

```
(base) user:Desktop username$ cd z3
(base) user:z3 username$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  RELEASE_NOTES   contrib     package
LICENSE.txt build       doc     scripts
README-CMake.md cmake       examples    src
README.md   configure   noarch      todo.txt
```

I need the scripts directory and the files in it in order to start the build. any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: The executable should be already there in the `bin` directory. Is it not?

Comment: @alias Yes, it is there. When I try to execute it I get an error message.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: @alias error: “z3” cannot be opened.

Comment: Check the permissions. Does it have executable perms? If not, issue `chmod a+x ...path-to-bin-file..`

Comment: @alias I have already fixed the problem and answered my question. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a release from this link:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/z3/4.8.4-1build1

when unzipped it had all the files needed to further the installation